# ReceiveAsync creates an exception when socket accepts a new connection after closing the old one

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

```
public class AsynchronousClient
{

    private const int port = 7777;

    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public class AppServer
    {
        Socket serverSocket = null;
        void accept()
        {
            SocketAsyncEventArgs e = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            e.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(e_Completed);

            bool raiseEvent = serverSocket.AcceptAsync(e);
            while (true)
            {
                if (!raiseEvent)
                    AcceptCallback(e);
            }
        }
        public void Start()
        {
            serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), 7777));
            serverSocket.Listen(100);
            serverSocket.Blocking = false;

            accept();
        }

        void e_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {

            AcceptCallback(e);
        }
        Socket clientSocket;
        private void AcceptCallback(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            SocketAsyncEventArgs readEventArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            readEventArgs.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            readEventArgs.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(readEventArgs_Completed);

            clientSocket = e.AcceptSocket;

            while (true)
            {
                allDone.Reset();
                bool raiseEvent = clientSocket.ReceiveAsync(readEventArgs); // <-- Error goes here
                if (!raiseEvent)
                    ReceiveCallback(readEventArgs);
                allDone.WaitOne();
            }
        }

        void readEventArgs_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            ReceiveCallback(e);
        }

        private void ReceiveCallback(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            allDone.Set();
            if (e.BytesTransferred > 0)
                clientSocket.Send(e.Buffer);
            else
            {
                accept(); }
        }

        private void SendCallback(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
    public static int Main(String[] args)
    {
        AppServer a = new AppServer();
        a.Start();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Hello. The idea of this code is to run the program, connect with netcat, and whatever i send from netcat, it needs to be echoed back to it. It works fine, until i close netcat, reopen it, connect to the server and when i send a message, it crashes on ReceievAsync. It says:"An asynchronous socket operation is already in progress using this SocketAsyncEventArgs instance.". I can't figure out why. Does anyone understand why?

Comment: Have you looked in to `TCPListener`? They are a tad easier to use.

Comment: I will have a look, but this is the preffered method. This is a sample i made to understand how those things work, but eventually i will need to integrate it in a bigger project, which uses events. So this method would better fit my project.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a loop in the `AcceptCallback`, instead you should call the `serverSocket.AcceptAsync(e);` at the end of the method.

At the end of `ReceiveCallback` you should call the clientSocket.ReceiveAsync(readEventArgs) again to continue receiving. (not loop needed)

```
while (true)
{
    if (!raiseEvent)
        AcceptCallback(e);
}

// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Doesn't look right....
```

---

I never used the ReceiveAsync. The BeginReceive/EndReceive are much easier.